# Convert record name from lookup field to string field value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, opportunity, case, string

I'd like to use the name of the opportunity, which a case is being created from, as the case Subject, for easy reference.

My cases are being created using a custom button & JavaScript. I can't find an example of code which converts the Opportunity Name into a string anywhere so that I can then use this value to populate Subject, is this possible?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 

try{ 
var recToCreate = new sforce.SObject("Case");  
recToCreate.OwnerId = "00G18000000Ntra";  
recToCreate.Opportunity__c = '{!Opportunity.Id}';  
recToCreate.AccountId = '{!Opportunity.AccountId}';  
recToCreate.Subject = {!Opportunity.Name};  

var result = sforce.connection.create([recToCreate]); 

  if(result[0].success == "true"){
    location.reload();
  }
  else{
      alert("An Error has Occurred. Error:" + result[0].errors.message);
   }
 }
 catch(e){
   alert("An Error has Occurred. Error:" + e);
}
```

The above returns "Unexpected identifier"

Comment: Can you share your previous code so that we may help you ?

Comment: Sure, I've added it.

Comment: It looks like you forgot quotes around `{!Opportunity.Name}`.

Comment: Alex if Namfuak answer resolved your issue .Pls ask him to add as answer

Comment: @Namfuak if you hadn't realized already, you've answered my question, please feel free to add the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot quotes around `{!Opportunity.Name}`.  The line should read:

```
recToCreate.Subject = '{!Opportunity.Name}';
```

Without the quotes, the browser interprets the name of the Opportunity as an identifier, which is why you get the error you are reporting.